# How to Query if doesn't know which table has the data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have following tables:

`TableA`: `Date`, `OrderNum`, `RejectionType`

`TableB`: `OrderNum`, `MaterialNum`, `Size`

`TableC`: `MaterialNum`, `Cost`

`TableB2`: `OrderNo`, `MaterialNo`, `Size`

`TableC2`: `MaterialNum`, `Cost`

`TableA` will always have multiple rows for a `Date`, and in those multiple rows of `OrderNum`, some of `OrderNum` exists in `TableB`, and some exists in `TableB2`, we don't know. Every row in `TableB` or `TableB2` has a according `MaterialNum`, we don't know it is in `TableC` or `TableC2`.

And also, although OrderNum in TableB has same attribute as OrderNo TableB2, since the column namesare different, I can not use `(... Union ...) As b where b.OrderNum = a.OrderNum`

How to query so that I can get following columns

Date, OrderNum, RejectionType, MaterialNum, Size, Cost

```
where TableA.Date = @Date
```

Thanks！

Comment: So `TableA` will always have a row for an order, the other ones are optional?  And are we talking SQL Server here, or MySQL?

Comment: @Andrew I just modified the question. Thanks

Comment: Well, for querying within the tables on a single server, I think you need to look into [Outer Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).  As Ollie pointed out below, trying to query across servers is complex.

Comment: This seems to be about SQL Server, not MySQL. I changed the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your alternate tables `TableB2` and `TableC2` are on a different physical server than your `TableA`, you aren't going to be able to do this in pure MySQL-dialect SQL unless you can construct a federated database.

That's a large undertaking, and you should address the question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ for how to do it.

Original Questioner. I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio 2008, and I already linked two servers. I think once linked, I'll be able to do it?

Ollie Jones: As long as you can do something like this in a SQL statement you can probably make this happen.

```
SELECT A.Date, A.OrderNum, A.RejectionType,
       Q.Source, Q.MaterialNum, Q.Size
  FROM Server1.TableA AS A
  LEFT JOIN  (
          SELECT 'Primary' AS Source,
                 OrderNum, 
                 MaterialNum, Size
            FROM Server1.TableB
           UNION ALL  /* pulls together contents from two tables */
          SELECT 'Secondary' AS Source,
                 OrderNo AS OrderNum,  /* alias makes column names conform in UNION */ 
                 MaterialNum, Size
            FROM Server2.TableB2
        ) AS Q ON Q.OrderNum = A.OrderNum
 WHERE TableA.Date = @Date
```

The `Source` column I created presents either `Primary` or `Secondary` in the result set to indicate whether the information came from `TableB` or `TableB2`. If you don't want it, you definitely don't need to use it.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio 2008, and I already linked two servers. I think once linked, I'll be able to do it?

Comment: Yes, I am using msoft SQL. I wanted to try your query, but for OrderNum, in one table it is named as OrderNum, in another, it is named OrderNo. But you use Q.OrderNum for both of the tables. What can I do if the names are different?

Comment: See my edit. You can use column aliases so all the contributions to a UNION have conforming column names.

Comment: it worked! Thank you very much! Just not very clearly understood your Q.Source and SELECT 'Primary'/'Secondary' AS Source. Because I didn't want a column called Source to appear, so I deleted Q.Source, it still worked. So what does SELECT 'Primary'/'Secondary' AS Source do here exactly?